# Raspberry Pi 4B cannot run Linux XMRig

Tags: pi-4, headless

I'm running a headless Raspberry Pi 4b connected to Ethernet and controlled via SSH from my MacBook Pro. I used scp to move XMRig for Linux over to it, preset to mine. However, when attempting to run the file with the command ./xmrig, it will not run and gives the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls
xmrig
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd xmrig
pi@raspberrypi:~/xmrig $ ls
xmrig-6.16.2
pi@raspberrypi:~/xmrig $ cd xmrig-6.16.2/
pi@raspberrypi:~/xmrig/xmrig-6.16.2 $ ls
config.json  SHA256SUMS  xmrig
pi@raspberrypi:~/xmrig/xmrig-6.16.2 $ ./xmrig
-bash: ./xmrig: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
pi@raspberrypi:~/xmrig/xmrig-6.16.2 $
```

What does this mean? Why won't it execute? Is there a version of XMRig for the Raspberry Pi specifically?

Comment: Are you using a version made for the Arm chip in the Pi or for a different architecture?

Comment: follow the ubuntu build basic options via command line
https://xmrig.com/docs/miner/build/ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Linux versions from Github for xmrig, they are all X64, not ARM. They are compild for a different processor and will therefore not run on the Pi.

So, unless you found a version specifically for the Pi, your best bet would be to download the source ans compile on th Pi. In the `tar.gz` for the sourcecode, there should be some read-me or install file that will give hints on how to compile and install it.

Comment: I did that and it's up and running, thanks!